# How to make sure write only if data does not exist in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I have two methods in my server application:

boolean isMessageExist(messageId) which execute below query:

> SELECT messageId from message Where messageId =1;

insertMessage(int messageId,String data) which execute below query:

> INSERT INTO message (messageId,data) VALUES (1, xyz);

In my code I am doing below to meet the required that "only insert if message does not exist".

```
if(!isMessageExist(1)){
insertMessage(1,"xyz")
}
```

But above code is not working if request for same messageId comes almost simultaneously.

i.e at time T0 ... the Read1(1), Write1(1) and Read2(1), Write2(1) are happening at the same time since the two requests were sent from the client at the same time. Is there a way make those request in sequence at serverside. I mean Read2(1) should always get the result Write1(1) ?

I don't want to USE CAS operation if IF NOT EXISTS due to performance overhead.
 Is there any other way to achieve my requirement? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Using Cassandra's light weight transactions (LWT) IF NOT EXISTS should be both less expensive then what you are currently doing and satisfy your requirement for uniqueness.

```
INSERT INTO message( messageId, data ) VALUES ( 1, xyz ) IF NOT EXISTS
```

You can test and verify the performance, but two round trips (read, write) is almost certainly more expensive than a single INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS.

Alternatively, if you can redesign your application so it uses UPSERTS -- where new values simply overwrites old data, that would be even better and use a more native Cassandra style.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think the LWT will be more expensive as per https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html . It says "These four phases of paxos protocol require four round trips between a node proposing a lightweight transaction and any cluster replicas involved in the transaction. Performance will be affected. Consequently, reserve lightweight transactions for situations where concurrency must be considered." . But i will verify that.

Comment: Note its not simply 4>2.  A LTW requires "four round trips between a node proposing a lightweight transaction and any cluster replicas involved in the transaction" vs your current round two trips between the client driver and server.  So, performance testing both should give you the facts you need to make a decision.